# How to clear default access rights in odoo using xml

Tags: xml, odoo-14, access-rights

Any idea on how to clear the value of a specific field in Users Settings? 
Example: In Users > Accounting > Accounting is set to `Accountant` by default
I would like to write it by xml which will be located in the security folder. I am using Odoo 14

This what I did:

```
<record id="group_user_id"
    model="res.groups">
    <field name="name">Payroll Test</field>
    <field name="category_id" ref="module_category_id"/>
    <field name="implied_ids" eval="[(3,ref('hr.group_hr_user'))]" />
</record>
```

but still it doesn't reset the setting of this particular field. Which part did I miss? Thanks in advance

Comment: settings>manage users>select your user>access rights> remove default rights whatever you want

Comment: you can use this code with xpath for give a access : <attribute name="groups">your_module.your_secururity_group</attribute>